# How to always Show IP Address (disable Private Relay) for a specific website?

Tags: ios, icloud, privacy, ipados, mobile-safari

I want to use my iPad & iPhone to access a website that is behind a firewall and is only accessible to IP addresses on a whitelist.

I can do this temporarily, for a single tab only, by:

1. Load the URL
2. Let it timeout
3. Tap ‘Aa’
4. Tap ‘Show IP Address’
5. Reload the URL

However this does not persist across tabs/reloads per:

*Apple Docs > [Manage iCloud Private Relay for specific websites, networks, or system settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102022) > If a website doesn't work with Private Relay*

It also doesn’t seem to work for URLs that are IP addresses rather than hostnames.

How can I set a website to ALWAYS show my real IP address? I.E. Never use Private Relay.